# Importing files from another folder in python

Tags: python, sys

I am trying to import files from other files. I checked out examples but I am still confused.

The structure of the folder is something like:

```
 Main folder
 ---->test.py
 ---->Folder1
      ----> folder2
            -------> script2.1.py
            -------> script2.2.py
            -------> script2.3.py
      ----> folder3
            -------> script3.1.py
            -------> script3.2.py
            -------> script3.3.py
      ----> folder4
            -------> script4.1.py
            -------> script4.2.py
            -------> script4.3.py
```

My intention is to include `script2.1 to script4.3` in `test.py`. I used `sys.append` and included the paths of folder1, folder2 and folder3 separately. Still there appears to be some issue. Can I get some help on this?

Comment: please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Yeah, that makes it easier..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this?

```
  import Folder1.folder2.script2.1.py
```